# VB.Net Chart Control - Can I bind data to different series from the different tables in my Dataset?

Tags: vb.net, charts, datatable, dataset

I think my subject sums up what I am interested in knowing. I am looking to create a chart where Series1 is from Table1, Series2 is from Table2 in the given Dataset.

My code below doesn't throw any errors, but it appears to be grabbing the data for each series from the first table.

```
    Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
    Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New(ByVal ChartData As DataSet)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
    Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
    Dim DataSeries(ChartData.Tables.Count - 1) As Series
    Dim Chart1 = New Chart()
    Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
    Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)

    Chart1.DataSource = ChartData

    For index As UShort = 0 To ChartData.Tables.Count - 1
        DataSeries(index) = New Series()
        DataSeries(index).Name = ChartData.Tables(index).TableName
        Chart1.Series.Add(DataSeries(index))

        Chart1.Series(index).XValueMember = ChartData.Tables(index).Columns(0).ColumnName
        Chart1.Series(index).YValueMembers = ChartData.Tables(index).Columns(1).ColumnName
    Next

    Chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Chart1.TabIndex = 0


    End Sub
    End Class
```

Edit: Apparently I can get the results I expected by iterating through and setting the points from the data... but this approach seems like it wouldn't be speedy for large datasets. Is there a better way to be doing this?

```
    Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
    Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New(ByVal ChartData As DataSet)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
    Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
    Dim DataSeries(ChartData.Tables.Count - 1) As Series
    Dim Chart1 = New Chart()
    Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
    Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)

    For index As UShort = 0 To ChartData.Tables.Count - 1
        DataSeries(index) = New Series()
        DataSeries(index).Name = ChartData.Tables(index).TableName
        Chart1.Series.Add(DataSeries(index).Name)

        For RowIndex As UShort = 0 To ChartData.Tables(index).Rows.Count - 1
                    Chart1.Series(DataSeries(index).Name).Points.AddXY(ChartData.Tables(index).Rows(RowIndex).Item(0), ChartData.Tables(index).Rows(RowIndex).Item(1))
                Next
            Next

            Chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            Chart1.TabIndex = 0

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: AFAIK, there's no other way of doing that. You'll have to add all the desired points manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the answer to this question. Apparently you have to add the data points manually.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Public Class Form1

Public Sub New(ByVal ChartData As DataSet)
' This call is required by the designer.
InitializeComponent()
' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
Dim DataSeries(ChartData.Tables.Count - 1) As Series
Dim Chart1 = New Chart()
Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)

Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
Chart1.Legends.Add(Legend1)

For index As UShort = 0 To ChartData.Tables.Count - 1
    DataSeries(index) = New Series()
    DataSeries(index).Name = ChartData.Tables(index).TableName
    Chart1.Series.Add(DataSeries(index).Name)

    For RowIndex As UShort = 0 To ChartData.Tables(index).Rows.Count - 1
                Chart1.Series(DataSeries(index).Name).Points.AddXY(ChartData.Tables(index).Rows(RowIndex).Item(0), ChartData.Tables(index).Rows(RowIndex).Item(1))
            Next
        Next

        Chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Chart1.TabIndex = 0

    End Sub
End Class
```